# I get this strange error 'System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView' is not marked as serializable

Tags: wpf, cloning, listcollectionview

I have a method which clones a class. This class contain subclasses and properties etc.
Is it causing due to ICollectionView-Property?
How to detect where the problem is? I mean which property or class is not marked serialized or something? Very confusing...

Error:
Type 'System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView' in Assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to serialize a .NET Framework type that is not marked with `SerializableAttribute`.

You won't be able to change that or get it working with the binary serializer - you need to store that data in another type that you can serialize, mark this `ListCollectionView` with `NonSerializedAttribute` and then on deserialization you can repopulate it manually (using [`IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.ondeserialization%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Comment: In fact, similar stuff I have done with other classes, they are working fine, but bit puzzled with this one!

Comment: Is it possible to identify the "problem" member causing the issues??

Comment: @Ravi It'll be the member that is of type `ListViewCollection` in whatever class you are trying to serialize. Because you don't have access to this source you won't be able to put the attribute on this type.

Comment: I gone thru entire code all over again and checked for [field:nonserialised] for events/delegates as well as [seriazable] attributes on class, etc. but still getting this error!

Comment: @Ravi Does your class derive from another class? As in `MyClass : BaseClass`.